# Python zip method and rounding behaviour

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding

Just seen what seems a rather curious behaviour in the python `zip()` built-in. I passed it a Numpy array of rounded decimals but it spits out an expanded version.

This the original array, my goal is to generate a dictionary with the proportion of occupancy of each unique element. `np` is Numpy.

```
 a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1])
```

So I go doing

```
elems, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
```

which spits `(array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 2, 1]))`. Correct. But now I want the proportion, not the count (rounded to the third digit), so I do

```
counts = np.round(counts/a.size, 3)
```

which gives `array([ 0.571,  0.286,  0.143])` for `counts`. Now into zipping this into the sought dict:

```
dict(zip(*(elems, counts)))
```

This spits `{1: 0.57099999999999995, 2: 0.28599999999999998, 3: 0.14299999999999999}`, so looks like the rounded counts have seen some digits added!

Comment: No, this is simply `numpy` *printing* things differently than a regular `float` object.

Answer (score 5):

Numpy just displays a different amount of significant digits when printing `numpy` arrays. You can adjust the printing precision with [`set_printoptions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

Example using your data:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1])
elems, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
counts = np.round(counts/a.size, 3)
np.set_printoptions(precision=20)
print(counts)
```

outputs:

```
[ 0.57099999999999995204  0.28599999999999997646  0.14299999999999998823]
```